# How to use sed to add a comma at the end of a specific line

Tags: shell, sed

The content of /etc/docker/daemon.json is:

```
{
    "runtimes": {
        "nvidia": {
            "path": "nvidia-container-runtime",
            "runtimeArgs": []
        }
    },
    "log-driver": "json-file"
}
```

The first Question :

I want to add a comma at the end of the line containing the log-driver string, how should I write it using the sed command?

The modified content is shown below:

```
{
    "runtimes": {
        "nvidia": {
            "path": "nvidia-container-runtime",
            "runtimeArgs": []
        }
    },
    "log-driver": "json-file",
}
```

The second quesion:

I want to add something under the log-driver line, how should I do it using sed?

The modified content is shown below:

```
{
    "runtimes": {
        "nvidia": {
            "path": "nvidia-container-runtime",
            "runtimeArgs": []
        }
    },
    "log-driver": "json-file",
    "log-opts": { 
       "max-size": "50m", 
       "max-file": "5" 
    }
}
```

Comment: Make the second question another question.

Comment: I assume this really is a single question about how to add additional properties via sed. If you can use/install it I suggest to use something like https://jqlang.github.io/jq/ instead.

Comment: Are you aware that adding that comma makes the JSON invalid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend a JSON-specific tool to manipulate JSON data

```bash
jq '.["log-opts"] = {"max-size": "50m", "max-file": "5"}' daemon.json
```

```json
{
  "runtimes": {
    "nvidia": {
      "path": "nvidia-container-runtime",
      "runtimeArgs": []
    }
  },
  "log-driver": "json-file",
  "log-opts": {
    "max-size": "50m",
    "max-file": "5"
  }
}
```

To overwrite the original file:

1. ```bash
   jq '...' daemon.json > daemon.json.tmp && mv daemon.json{.tmp,}
   ```
2. use `sponge` from the `moreutils` package

   ```bash
   jq '...' daemon.json | sponge daemon.json
   ```

Answer (score 0):

sed /log/s/$/,/g file;

.....................